# Swift - check if JSON is valid

Tags: json, swift

```
let data = NSData(contentsOfFile: "myfile")
let jsonString = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
let jsonData: NSData! = jsonString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
var validJson = false

if (NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: nil, error: &error) != nil) {
    validJson = true
}
```

I want the code above to only set `validJson` true when the contents of jsonData is actually valid JSON. At the moment if I pump anything into the "myfile" file which can be seen in the code, `validJson` is **always** true.

How can I fix this so `validJson` is only true when it's actually valid JSON?

Comment: Could you give an example of invalid data that is actually parsed and reported as valid?

Comment: @Sulthan I just replaced myfile with a HTML file and this is still setting `validJson` to true.

Comment: Make the test case simplier by just using a constans String for `jsonString`.

Comment: @zaph Thanks, I will try setting the value of that variable directly now.

Comment: @zaph Sadly this made no difference, I literally just slammed the keyboard with random letters and it still think it's valid.

Comment: Why do you convert the NSData to NSString and then back to NSData?

Comment: If you copy your code as is, there are some compilation errors regarding unwrapping. I guess the code you have posted is not the real code you are testing?

Answer (score 12):

```
isValidJSONObject:
```

*Returns a Boolean value that indicates whether a given object can be converted to JSON data.*

***Code Example***

```
    let jsonString = "{}"
    let jsonData = jsonString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

    if JSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(jsonData) {
        print("Valid Json")
    } else {
        print("InValid Json")
    }
```

[API REFERENCE:](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsjsonserialization/1418461-isvalidjsonobject)

Comment: This answer is not working for me, please review this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40635993/nsjsonserialization-isvalidjsonobject-returns-false-for-received-data-from-venue

Comment: Yeah this answer is wrong. `isValidJSONObject` actually does the reverse. `Returns a Boolean value that indicates whether a given object can be converted to JSON data.`

Comment: this does not check if a json string is valid.

Comment: This answer is wrong and should be removed from the accepted answer. You need to check
```
try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) != nil
```
is true or not if you want to check the Data object is the valid JSON.

Answer (score 3):

I have tested the following:

```
let jsonString = ""

let jsonString = "<html></html>"

let jsonString = "{}"
```

with code:

```
let jsonData: NSData = jsonString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
var error: NSError? = nil

let validJson = (NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options:nil, error: &error) != nil)

println("Valid JSON: \(validJson)")
```

First two strings print `false`, the third prints `true` as expected.

I think you are probably loading a different file than you expect.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. Seemed to be two variables with the same name in production code that was causing the issue.