# NSJSONSerialization isValidJSONObject returns false for received data from Venue search endpoint

Tags: ios, foursquare

Xcode 8.1 Deployment target iOS 9.0

I'm getting an array of compact venue objects as expected from Foursquare Venue Search endpoint in...

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session dataTask:(NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTask didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
```

When I check the *data* object using...

```
if ([NSJSONSerialization isValidJSONObject:data])
```

i get a false.

Can someone tell me what is wrong over here?

Edit:
Here is the complete if block (after adding typecast to *data* in if block)...

```
    id foundationObject;

NSLog(@"data:- %@",data);
if ([NSJSONSerialization isValidJSONObject:(id)data])
{
    foundationObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
    NSLog(@"venues foundation object:- %@",foundationObject);
}
```

Earlier the code didn't have the if block. just...

```
id foundationObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
```

The change was made when I realized (using breakpoint just after the above statement) that *foundationObject* was nil even though *data* wasn't.

Note: this worked fine earlier when I shipped my app for iOS 9.x in march. Could the version of the Venue Endpoint being called be making a difference?

Answer (score 6):

What you're testing here is for NSData. The input for `isValidJSONObject` is `id` not `NSData`

```
+ (BOOL)isValidJSONObject:(id)obj;
```

It returns `YES` if obj can be converted to JSON data (`NSData`), otherwise NO.

Also, according to documentation,

> An object that may be converted to JSON must have the following properties:
>
> 1. The top level object is an NSArray or NSDictionary.
> 2. All objects are instances of NSString, NSNumber, NSArray, NSDictionary, or NSNull.
> 3. All dictionary keys are instances of NSString.
> 4. Numbers are not NaN or infinity.
>
> Calling isValidJSONObject: or attempting a conversion are the definitive ways to tell if a given object can be converted to JSON data.

For converting `NSData` to JSONObject, you can use the following code

```
NSError *error;
id jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
if (!error) {
    // successfully done.
}else {
   NSLog(@"error: %@", error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Please note that to find out what's wrong with jsonData(`NSData`) you're receiving from the server, you have to pass `NSError` object into the method as shown in the above code. If conversion of `NSData` into jsonObject fails, you can find out why according to that.

Please look in to this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ErrorHandlingCocoa/CreateCustomizeNSError/CreateCustomizeNSError.html) for more information on using `NSError` objects in Objective-C

Comment: hello. i edited the question. please check. was already doing what you mentioned.

Comment: Please check my answer. You're not doing what I mentioned in the answer. You are not passing `NSError` object in to the method. When you do that, you will get the `error` value which says what went wrong. I'll edit it to give you a clear cut answer to find where it went wrong.

Comment: hi. this is the error i am getting... "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set."

Comment: i changed the reading option to "allow fragments" and i got ...error "Garbage at end."

Comment: Check with your server side. Any JSON text should start with array or dictionary. I believe you can't just send plain text data from your server. Also, as apple says in the documentation, the top level object should be array or dictionary.

Comment: i am calling foursqaure venues endpoint with code i wrote a year and a half back. i think they have changed the way to query their database. i cant find my client id and secret on their website.

Comment: I think you have escape characters in your NSData. That might be one of the reasons for this.

Answer (score 3):

You are using a wrong method here `isValidJSONObject` will tell you whether JSON object (id) will be converted to JSON data or not.

As per the [doc](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsjsonserialization/1418461-isvalidjsonobject)

> Returns a Boolean value that indicates whether a given object can be
>   converted to JSON data.
>        YES if obj can be converted to JSON data, otherwise NO.

If you want to check Data then you should use `JSONObjectWithData:options:error:` and check if it is nil or not.

**Edit**

You need to first convert your Data to `NSDictionary` or `NSArray` like this

```
NSMutableDictionary * dict=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
```

then check if `dict` is a valid son or not like this

```
if([NSJSONSerialization isValidJSONObject:dict]){
    NSLog(@"dict is a valid JSON");
}else{
    NSLog(@"dict is not valid JSON");
}
```

Comment: please check the question again. i made an edit. was doing the same. however the object that captured the return value of JSONObjectWithData remains nil.

Comment: @AceNeerav Updated my answer

Comment: There's no point to checking `isValidJSONObject` after converting the data using `JSONObjectWithData`.  If the data didn't represent a valid json object then `JSONObjectWithData` would return nil.

Comment: @AceNeerav You can't  check NSData with `isValidJSONObject ` check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17149868/isvalidjsonobject-not-working-as-expected

Comment: saw the link. thanks. and i was expecting an error message but realized i had passed nil in error: parameter! (as pointed out Krishna)