# Swift - JSONSerialization invalid JSON

Tags: swift, healthkit

I'm accessing health records via `HealthKit`, the issue is when I inspecting the `FHIR` data, it isn't valid JSON data when checking using `isValidJSONObject`. I'm not too familiar with `JSONSerialization`, this is my first real use for it.

```swift
let jsonObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: fhirRecord.data, options: [])
print(jsonObject)
```

```
{
    lotNumber = 11111;
    occurrenceDateTime = "2021-01-01”;
    patient =     {
        reference = "resource:0";
    };
    performer =     (
                {
            actor =             {
                display = “Some place here“;
            };
        }
    );
    resourceType = Immunization;
    status = completed;
    vaccineCode =     {
        coding =         (
                        {
                code = 1;
                system = “URL_HERE”;
            },
                        {
                code = 28581000087106;
                system = “URL_HERE”;
            }
        );
    };
}
```

Comment: Can you show how you try to validate the JSON and where the error is printed? Since you succeed in printing `jsonObject`, the parsing actually succeeds.

Comment: So you tested `isValidJSONObject` on `jsonObject`? Because `isValidJSONObject` is from a `(NS)Dictionary`/`(NS)Array` to know if it can be `(NS)Data`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40635993/nsjsonserialization-isvalidjsonobject-returns-false-for-received-data-from-venue Currently, it parsed `fhirRecord.data` correctly you have the print of a `NSDictionary`. What did you expect? If you expected more "JSON String", then it's `let jsonStr = String(data fhirRecord.data, encoding: .utf8)` that you wanted...

Comment: Ahh, thanks for the correction! I was looking for `let jsonStr = String(data fhirRecord.data, encoding: .utf8)`. I was looking to create some `Codable` data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @RobNapier pointed out I needed `FHIRModels`, from Apple. I'm able to get data more easily than using a messy `Codable` data approach manually.

```swift
import ModelsR4

let resource = try decoder.decode(Immunization.self, from: data)
```

print output is proper

```
28581000087106
28581000087106
```

Answer (score 2):

JSONSerialization has nothing to do with Codable, and generally should be avoided in Swift. It's only in Swift because it's bridged from ObjC, and has significant limitations even in ObjC.

`isValidJSONObject` doesn't tell you that JSON data is valid. It tells you that an ObjC object could be converted to JSON by JSONSerialization (again, completely unrelated to Codable).

Get rid of the JSONSerialization. Plug your JSON into https://app.quicktype.io to generate a Codable model for it, and use JSONDecoder to decode it. JSONSerialization will only give a `[String: Any]` which is extremely hard to work with in Swift (and not great in ObjC). JSONDecoder will give you a proper struct.

Comment: That’s what I’m aiming for but like I said FHIR data is a bit different. I’m on the right path, not yet there but some answers did help me out.

Comment: More complex JSON is still very parseable using JSONDecoder. You can't always using app.quicktype.io, particularly if the keys are dynamic, but Decodable can handle all kinds of unusual structures. That said,Apple has a package specifically for FHIR structures that I'd look at: https://github.com/apple/FHIRModels

Comment: Perfect, that seems more what I’m looking for!

Comment: You can learn more about Health Records API and FHIRModels in these WWDC talks: WWDC18: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/706/ and WWDC20: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10669